# Problema com async task

Tags: c#

Estou batendo a cabeça pra conseguir resolver mas não consigo, o erro que está dando é

`An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending.`

<sub>source error:</sub>

`An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.`

Estou enviando uma requisição para gerar um boleto, mas está erro de asynchronous. Estou usando o plugin [Fluent](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/fluent-http/) para isso

código:

```
public async Task<FileStreamResult> Teste(){
    var response = url.WithHeaders(
        new
        {
            Authorization =
            "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(
                Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ApiKey + ":" + Password)),
            ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        }).PostUrlEncodedAsync(boleto).Result;

    var pdfBytes = response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
    pdfBytesResult = pdfBytes;
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(pdfBytesResult);
    return new FileStreamResult(ms, "application/pdf");
}
```

**O problema só ocorre quando o site está em produção(IIS), quando local o mesmo não acontece**

Comment: Tente nunca usar `.Result` de uma `Task` quando quer trabalhar de forma assíncrona, nesses casos você está forçando o código a ser síncrono, e forçar algo síncrono dentro de algo assíncrono piora a performance, é pior do que trabalhar direto com sincronismo.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O problema não estava no código e sim no proxy, que estava bloqueando o acesso externo.

Comment: Cara, isso não tem não tem nada a ver com o erro que você postou no início.

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa usar o `await` para esperar a execução de  `ReadAsByteArrayAsync`

```
var pdf = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
```

Comment: Da erro: ```'byte[]' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'byte[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)```

Comment: O certo é: `await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync()`